# Is there a way to restart SYSTEMD services when they are reach their CpuQuota or MemoryHigh limits?

Tags: systemd, service, memory-usage, outofmemoryerror

The problem is about the systemd services. I know we can limit the Memory Usage or Cpu usage of services but my question is that is there a way to restart service when it reaches to its Memory high limit(or cpu)? Because i want to know that if the service is out of memory(leak) it has to restart again. I used these in unit file for limiting memory and cpu of service:

```
MemoryHigh=100K
MemoryMax=150K
CPUQuota=10%
```

Comment: Conceptually l think the limits in a systemd service unit  are designed to protect all the other services on your system from a run-away process and not the process itself - I think such a runaway service  is expected to either gracefully recover from a MemoryHigh or  to die when the hard limit MemoryMax  is reached (and then systemd can restart it for you with `Restart=on-failure` ) see https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html and the references therein - I think you need external monitoring on occurrences of MemoryHigh events